# Firebase: How to organize data that is synced to many groups

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem regarding the organization of my data. What I want to achieve:

**What I want to achieve**
TL/DR: One data point updated in real time in many different groups, how to organize?

Each user sets a daily goal (goal) he wants to achieve
Upon working each user increases his time to get closer to his daily goal (daily_time_spent). (say from 1 minute spent to 2 minute spent).

Each user can also be in a group with other users.
If there is a group of users, you can see each other's progress (goal/daily_time_spent) in real time (real time being every 2-5 minutes, for cost reasons).
It will later also be possible to set a daily goal for a specific group. Your own daily goal would contribute to each of the groups.
Say you are part of three groups with the goals 10m/20m/30m and you already did 10m then you would complete the first group and have done 50% of the second group and 30% of the third group. Your own progress (daily_time_spent) contributes to all groups, regardless of the individual goals (group_daily_goal).

**My ideas**
How would I organize that? One idea is if a user increments his/her time, the time gets written down into each group the user is part of and then, when the user increases his time, it gets increased in each group he/she is part of. But this seems to be pretty inefficient, because I would potentially write the same data in many different places (coming from the background of a SQL-Developer, it might also be expensive?).

Another option: Each user tracks his time, say under userTimes/{user} and then there are the groups: groups/{groupname} with links to userTimes. But then I don't know how to get realtime updates.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries? Have you also considered using Cloud Firestore?

Comment: For every group, the user is part of, I want to get live updates of everybody's progress being their daily_time_spent. I want to get updates in "real time" (every 2-5 minutes) but the user could be in different groups. Then daily_time_spent for each user is the same across all groups.

Comment: So far, so good. So what have tried to achieve that?

Comment: I have two ideas: First idea: User A is in group 1/2/3. Each time user A increases daily_time_spent, the data gets updated in group 1,2 and 3. Then when you are in a group you listen to changes in group 1/2/3.

Comment: 2nd Idea: Each user uploads his data to dailyTimeSpent/A. In group 1/2/3 there is a reference to dailyTimeSpent/A. Then data is just on one point. But then I don't know how to listen to changes, because for example in group 1 ther would be members:[A,B,C]

Comment: In my opinion, both solutions might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approach can work fine, and there is no singular *best* approach here - as Alex said, it all depends on the use-cases of your app, and your comfort level with the code that is required for each of them.

1. Duplicating the data under each relevant user will complicate the code that performs the write operation, and store more data. But in return for that, reading the data will be really simple and scale very well to many users.
2. Reading the data from under all followed users will complicate the code that performs the read operation, and slow it down a bit (though not nearly as much as you may expect, as Firebase can [pipeline the requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)). But it does keep your data minimal and your write operations simple.

If you choose to duplicate the data, that is an operation that you can usually do well in a [(RTDB-triggered) Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), but it's also possible to do it through a [multi-path write operation from the client](https://firebase.blog/posts/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73).

Comment: Nice, thank you Frank for your help, then I'll take the first approach!